# How can a Google Sheets formula stay the same even if a column is deleted?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with a Google Sheet to maintain an attendance log for the most recent 10 weeks of an online group activity. I use `B1:K1` as my date headers. I use a `=COUNTIF()` function in my `L` column to see how many weeks they have attended out of the 10 displayed on the sheet.

I've been using the formula `=(COUNTIF(B4:K4, "Y")` to count how many "Y" marks there are for the person's attendance over the last 10 weeks (columns).

**The problem:**

As I am only recording the last 10 weeks, I delete the `B` column each time a new week rolls around. When I do this, my `L` column formula gets updated to reference `B4:J4` instead of `B4:K4`. I always insert one column to the right of `J` each week, but the formula still of course references `B4:J4`.

Please note that I have also tried using absolute cell references which does not work for what I need.

How can I make sure my formula never gets changed and always references `B4:K4`, even after deleting a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `INDIRECT` and a string to keep the references from updating:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B4:K4"),"Y")
```

Or a more dynamic option that gets your current row:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":K"&ROW()),"Y")
```